# How to sum data-price and insert it into a hidden input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, radio-button

I am summing-up the data-price attribute for multiple radio buttons and then trying to insert the result into a hidden input field.

I am able to sum up the price-data within the `span` in my HTML but I just can't get it to insert into the hidden input...

Should I combine both scripts? and if so, how would I do this?

Here is my HTML for reference...

```
<input type="radio" style="display:none;" id="cdjs" data-price="90" value="2BA" name="prod">
<label for="cdjs">
  <img src="../../images/prod1.png" style="width:42px;">
  <p>Product 1</p>
</label>


<span id="price"></span>


<input type="hidden" id="hiddenprice" name="price" value=''>
```

Here is my script that sums up the data-price..

```
function calcPrice() {
  var price = 0;
  $("input[type=radio][data-price]:checked").each(function(i, el) {
    price += +$(el).data("price");
  });
  $("#price").text(price);
}

$("input[type=radio]").on("change", calcPrice);
calcPrice();
```

and here is my script that should insert the result into the hidden input..

```
$(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    var checked = $(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked');
    $('#price').html(checked.data('price'));
    $('#hiddenprice').val(checked.data('price'));
  }).change();
});
```

Comment: Can you please edit your HTML to include the multiple checkboxes, so we can see how they relate to each other, and also to display them in the page so we can actually test your example

Comment: `$(this).find('input[type=radio]:checked')` won't find anything. You don't have any `<input>` elements that contain checkboxes. Inputs aren't container elements.

Comment: Why aren't you filling in the hidden input in `calcPrice()`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi, sorry I meant radio buttons not checkboxes, have corrected this in the question

Comment: @Barmar Hi, sorry I meant radios not checkboxes, my mistake, also yes I need to basically include part of the second script into the first but not sure how to structure it correctly

Comment: it doesn't matter what you meant. You can't have an input inside another input.

Comment: Why do you think you need the second script at all? Just add `$('#hiddenprice').val(price)` to the first script.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, thanks, but I am now getting `[object HTMLSpanElement]` inside the hidden input value

Comment: I think you misunderstood. That line should be added to the `calcPrice()` function, not the top-level of the script.

Comment: @Barmar Oh I see, sorry JS isnt my strong point, thank you for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: I just assumed it would be obvious that you would do this the same way as `$("#price").text(price);`. Why do you think there's any difference?

Comment: @Barmar Because I wasnt certain if I needed to have the `checked.data` part or anything else, also, is it possible to set the decimal point limit within the script? I'm getting results such as `300.50000001` whereas I need it more like a price i.e, `300.50`

Comment: Use `price.toFixed(2)` to get 2 decimal places.